# CSS basic layout: fixed navigation, stretching content, absolute footer

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to do a basic page layout where the navigation bar is always visible, the footer is at the bottom of the page and between the two there is the content.
If the content is too small the it should strech and push the footer to the boottom of the window.

I have the following code which is for some reason is scrollable and unwanted unused area appears after the footer.

https://jsfiddle.net/etLx01dj/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .navigation {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 4em;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .content {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 4em;
      }

      .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3em;
        background-color: red;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="navigation">
        <p>nav works</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>content works</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>footer works</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bonus question: is it possible to avoid `margin-top: 4em` for the content when navigation is fixed?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clean way of doing it, using flexbox:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

body>* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation,
.footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  min-height: 3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 1px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
}
.navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.85);
}
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.85);
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tall-content {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="navigation">
        <div>nav works</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" contentEditable="true">
        <p> Click and edit (copy/paste/delete) the content, to see how it works with various heights...
        
        <p>Maroon grapple Jolly Roger deadlights schooner gangway aft booty cutlass cackle fruit. Handsomely topgallant doubloon Jack Tar Jack Ketch landlubber or just lubber dance the hempen jig warp jib long clothes. Black spot red ensign bowsprit wench sheet nipperkin line gibbet scuppers careen.

        <p>Matey Yellow Jack furl nipper heave down Sink me ballast boatswain barkadeer bilge water. Brethren of the Coast transom bring a spring upon her cable Davy Jones' Locker draft tender trysail holystone Admiral of the Black jolly boat. Yo-ho-ho careen coxswain Yellow Jack capstan galleon Jack Tar spanker loaded to the gunwalls man-of-war.

        <p>Coffer plunder come about Sea Legs gun Jolly Roger squiffy barkadeer Plate Fleet sloop. Take a caulk knave Pirate Round Sail ho Jack Tar Gold Road topgallant cutlass cog grog. Hands walk the plank quarterdeck maroon aye Spanish Main haul wind boatswain coffer pinnace.

        <p>Maroon grapple Jolly Roger deadlights schooner gangway aft booty cutlass cackle fruit. Handsomely topgallant doubloon Jack Tar Jack Ketch landlubber or just lubber dance the hempen jig warp jib long clothes. Black spot red ensign bowsprit wench sheet nipperkin line gibbet scuppers careen.

        <p>Matey Yellow Jack furl nipper heave down Sink me ballast boatswain barkadeer bilge water. Brethren of the Coast transom bring a spring upon her cable Davy Jones' Locker draft tender trysail holystone Admiral of the Black jolly boat. Yo-ho-ho careen coxswain Yellow Jack capstan galleon Jack Tar spanker loaded to the gunwalls man-of-war.

        <p>Coffer plunder come about Sea Legs gun Jolly Roger squiffy barkadeer Plate Fleet sloop. Take a caulk knave Pirate Round Sail ho Jack Tar Gold Road topgallant cutlass cog grog. Hands walk the plank quarterdeck maroon aye Spanish Main haul wind boatswain coffer pinnace.
        
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div>footer works</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

No hard-coded margin/paddings, no absolute or fixed positioning. Footer and header have `flex-grow: 0` and content has `flex-grow: 1`, combined with `min-height: 100vh` on parent. If you're not comfortable giving `<body>` `display:flex`, use a wrapper, but I can assure you it works cross-browser.

Obviously, you can ignore the theming. I just wasn't a fan of the colors you picked :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, with little modifications I got what I wanted. I removed `overflow-y: auto;` from `content` to get an absolute footer at the bottom instead of a fixed one. For my case `body>*  padding: 1rem;` also caused some trouble with my changes so I removed that.
Fun fact, macbook screen edges are rounded and using `body height 100vh` causes a little empty space under the footer in firefox which I guess is not part of the viewport in it, while using 100% removes that empty space as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **code**:

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .navigation {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 4em;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .content {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 4em;
      }

      .footer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3em;
        background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="navigation">
        <p>nav works</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>content works</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>footer works</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help. It still has 2 flaws in browser. In firefox there is still a few pixel wide empty space after the footer. Though the content is not so big it pushes the footer out of the viewport and you need to scroll to see it.